# Sqoop query execution Error With Sucess

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, sqoop

While executing the sqoop query getting error message but after few second query executed successfully and table records are also imported successfully from sql server to hive.Number of records also matching with sql-server and hive.

Unable to get why error is throwing. I am sharing the log information, can any one explain the reason behind this. For the security reason i am hiding the IP's.

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://10.128.**.***:1433;database=COCO_Pilot" --username sa --password Passw0rd --table RO_Transaction --hive-import --create-hive-table --hive-table coco_pilot.ro_transaction --warehouse-dir /user/landing --hive-overwrite -m 1;
Warning: /usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/hbase does not exist! HBase imports will fail.
Please set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.
Warning: /usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
17/12/06 19:54:45 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6.2.6.2.0-205
17/12/06 19:54:45 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
17/12/06 19:54:45 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: Using Hive-specific delimiters for output. You can override
17/12/06 19:54:45 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: delimiters with --fields-terminated-by, etc.
17/12/06 19:54:45 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
17/12/06 19:54:45 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
17/12/06 19:54:46 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM [RO_Transaction] AS t WHERE 1=0
17/12/06 19:54:46 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/hadoop-mapreduce
Note: /tmp/sqoop-hdfs/compile/c592fdb7dc832a5adea6b13f299abeeb/RO_Transaction.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
17/12/06 19:54:48 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-hdfs/compile/c592fdb7dc832a5adea6b13f299abeeb/RO_Transaction.jar
17/12/06 19:54:48 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of RO_Transaction
17/12/06 19:54:49 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at slave1.snads.com/10.20.30.5:8050
17/12/06 19:54:49 INFO client.AHSProxy: Connecting to Application History server at slave1.snads.com/10.20.30.5:10200
17/12/06 19:54:52 INFO db.DBInputFormat: Using read commited transaction isolation
17/12/06 19:54:52 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
17/12/06 19:54:52 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1512027414889_0102
17/12/06 19:54:53 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1512027414889_0102
17/12/06 19:54:53 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://slave1.snads.com:8088/proxy/application_1512027414889_0102/
17/12/06 19:54:53 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1512027414889_0102
17/12/06 19:55:00 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1512027414889_0102 running in uber mode : false
17/12/06 19:55:00 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
17/12/06 19:55:19 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1512027414889_0102_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host 10.128.**.***, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.".
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:167)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:76)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:749)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host 10.128.**.***, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.".
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:220)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:165)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host 10.128.**.***, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.".
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:170)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1049)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:833)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:716)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:841)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBConfiguration.getConnection(DBConfiguration.java:302)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:213)
        ... 10 more

17/12/06 19:55:40 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
17/12/06 19:55:41 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1512027414889_0102 completed successfully
17/12/06 19:55:41 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 31
        File System Counters
                FILE: Number of bytes read=0
                FILE: Number of bytes written=165681
                FILE: Number of read operations=0
                FILE: Number of large read operations=0
                FILE: Number of write operations=0
                HDFS: Number of bytes read=87
                HDFS: Number of bytes written=199193962
                HDFS: Number of read operations=4
                HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
                HDFS: Number of write operations=2
        Job Counters
                Failed map tasks=1
                Launched map tasks=2
                Other local map tasks=2
                Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=475111
                Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
                Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=36547
                Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=36547
                Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=486513664
        Map-Reduce Framework
                Map input records=1827459
                Map output records=1827459
                Input split bytes=87
                Spilled Records=0
                Failed Shuffles=0
                Merged Map outputs=0
                GC time elapsed (ms)=136
                CPU time spent (ms)=21330
                Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=1431515136
                Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=13562888192
                Total committed heap usage (bytes)=1369964544
        File Input Format Counters
                Bytes Read=0
        File Output Format Counters
                Bytes Written=199193962
17/12/06 19:55:41 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 189.9662 MB in 52.4188 seconds (3.624 MB/sec)
17/12/06 19:55:41 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 1827459 records.
17/12/06 19:55:41 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Publishing Hive/Hcat import job data to Listeners
17/12/06 19:55:41 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM [RO_Transaction] AS t WHERE 1=0
17/12/06 19:55:42 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column id had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive
17/12/06 19:55:42 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column Transaction_Date had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive
17/12/06 19:55:42 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column Pump_No had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive
17/12/06 19:55:42 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column Nozzle_No had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive
17/12/06 19:55:42 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column product had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive
17/12/06 19:55:42 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column unit_price had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive
17/12/06 19:55:42 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column Volume had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive
17/12/06 19:55:42 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column Amount had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive
17/12/06 19:55:42 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column Start_Totlizer had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive
17/12/06 19:55:42 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column End_Totlizer had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive
17/12/06 19:55:42 INFO hive.HiveImport: Loading uploaded data into Hive
17/12/06 19:55:42 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.custom-extensions.root does not exist
17/12/06 19:55:42 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.custom-extensions.root does not exist

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/hive/lib/hive-common-1.2.1000.2.6.2.0-205.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
OK
Time taken: 2.146 seconds
Loading data to table coco_pilot.ro_transaction
Table coco_pilot.ro_transaction stats: [numFiles=1, numRows=0, totalSize=199193962, rawDataSize=0]
OK
Time taken: 0.725 seconds
```

Comment: Seems it is not able to connect in first few try. And letter it is getting connected. Try `telnet you IP on port for database`. Also use ping command to see any response time out. Seems more like network issue.

Comment: But why because ports are open and some times also unable to connect.

Comment: Try to use ping command with -t option for timeout. If it is there.

Comment: checked telnet with that sql server along with the port at the same time. It works fine.